# postgres_ext-serializer each_serializer Rails 5 adding custom JSON meta data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

I'm using Rails 5.2.3, postgres_ext (3.0.0), active_model_serializers (0.8.4), I am trying to render JSON data in the format of

```
{
    total: 500,
    totalNotFiltered: 500, 
    rows: [
      ...
    ]
}
```

I am able to get close but I am not able to get the additional custom fields added.

So far I have

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @people, each_serializer: PersonSerializer, root: :rows, meta{total: 500, totalNotFiltered: 500}}
end
```

This gives the correct root :rows, but the meta data isnt being added.

The postgres_ext gem does great in getting the JSON rows correctly, down from 190ms av to 25ms av, so I want to use this. I have tried FastJSON (Netflix) but that is far slower and again not easy to format the output generated.

It might be something simple here but I can fathom how to add the 2 elements missing. Ideas or suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

in array_serializer.rb of the postgres_ext-serializers-0.0.3 gem, I can hack this JSON string by adding the options I need, then added it as a patch for a temp solution. If someone has a better idea or way, please advise.

in the controller (this is for bootstraptable btw)

```
 render json: @people, each_serializer: PersonSerializer, root: :rows, total: @people_count,  totalNotFiltered: Person.all.count}
```

then serializer.rb

```
module IncludeMethods
  def to_json(*)
    root = @options.fetch(:root, self.class.root)
    total = @options[:total]
    totalNotFiltered = @options[:totalNotFiltered]
    if ActiveRecord::Relation === object && root != false
       total = "{\"total\":\"#{total}\",\"totalNotFiltered\":\"#{totalNotFiltered}\","
      _postgres_serializable_array.sub('{', total)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Its not the best but it works for now